# Django TabularInline: Discard empty rows

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django [`TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) in my Admin class to show related objects from another model. I know this feature is made primarily to edit related objects on the same page, but I set the fields readonly so I have a nice table to display related objects.

Django renders a nice table but when there is only 1 related object, it renders 3 empty rows. As I don't need editing functionality, I want to only show as much rows as there are objects.

There's the two options [`max_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num) and [`min_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.min_num), but as the number of related objects varies in my application, I can't set this to a static value.

Is there a way I can programmatically set it to the number of related objects?

Possibly not needed for this question, but here's my code anyway:

```
class RirDataInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RirData
    fields = ['netname', 'inetnum', 'review_status', 'active']
    readonly_fields = fields
    can_delete = False
    show_change_link = True


class CompanyRecordAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    search_fields = ['name']
    inlines = [
        RirDataInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) to 0

```
class RirDataInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RirData
    fields = ['netname', 'inetnum', 'review_status', 'active']
    readonly_fields = fields
    can_delete = False
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 0
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thank you.